# Why is variable not printed when we return object from function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I made a custom hook where I return a state. It is not printing the state value when I return an object from a custom hook, but it prints a value  when I return an array which has the state as its first element.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export default () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://5os4e.csb.app/data.json");
    setState(res.data);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fetchData();
    })();
  }, []);
// i am returning a object
  return { state };
};
```

Using like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const { st } = useTabData();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {JSON.stringify(st, null, 2)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

why is `st` value not printed? It is printed when I return an array.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-meadow-9l41z?file=/src/App.js:89-276

Comment: You're returning `{ state: state }`, but your deconstruction in App is looking for a `st` property, which is undefined. `return state;` in your hook and use something like `const tabData = useTabData();` (you can use any name now). To clarify: a quick fix for your current code would be `return { st: state }` in your custom hook. But that's a bad idea obviously. Just return `state` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to your code in couple of ways

**1st** way - you destruct your state

```
  const { state:st } = useTabData();
```

**2nd** way - directly call function

```
{JSON.stringify(useTabData().state, null, 2)}
```

> your passing and and accessing variable name should be same or you can use destructuring like 1st step to change variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Little hint for beginners

```js
// Return object
const myFunct1 = () => {
  // Return values
  const alpha = 1;
  const beta = 2;
  const gamma = 3;
  
  return { alpha, beta, gamma };
}

// Return array
const myFunct2 = () => {
  // Return values
  const alpha = 111;
  const beta = 222;
  const gamma = 333;
  
  return [alpha, beta, gamma];
}

// Get values from object return
let { alpha, beta, gamma } = myFunct1();
console.log(alpha, beta, gamma);

// Get values from array return
const [one, two, three] = myFunct2();
console.log(one, two, three);
```